# alfresco workflow model for upload file in task from out of repository

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn, alfresco-share

I'm designing a workflow to upload and revise document in alfresco.
I need to design a task which has a type and a file uploader in it.
It should can upload file from out of alfresco repository and it should has versioning aspect (something like adhoc task item selection, but I need to select my file from outside of alfresco repository).

how can I do that?

Comment: You are using explorer or share?

Comment: I'm using alfresco share.

Comment: you have to customize the workflow related pages

Comment: you have to customize the workflow related pages to add the upload components check out all the scripts responsible for rendering those pages and you can changes those scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be useful [Upload file during a worfklow](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/workflow/upload-file-during-wofklow-12072011-0823#p128862) from alfresco froums.